# A more efficient way to write multiple CASE statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,

  CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,

  CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN ( Table 1.FULL) END ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,

  CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN ( CASE WHEN Table 3.DO = 'Z' THEN 'Y' END ) END ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,


  CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN ( NVL(( Table2.COLUMN3), ( Table2.COLUMN3 )) ) END ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,


  CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table 4. COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN ( NVL(( Table2.COLUMN3), ( Table2.COLUMN3)) ) END ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,


  CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN ( Table 3.FULL) END ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,


  CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN ( ( Table2.COLUMN3) ) END ) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,


  CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  then CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1 ) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) 
  IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN ( ( Table2.COLUMN3) ) END ) IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) 
  IS NOT NULL AND ( Table.COLUMN2) IS NOT NULL 
  THEN CASE WHEN ( Table.COLUMN1) - ( Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ELSE 'N' END ) = 'Y' 
  THEN ( ( Table2.COLUMN3) ) END ) < 90 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END END ) = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this statement?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: My question is, is there a more efficient way to write  this 'case when' statement?

Comment: To be honest, that SQL is quite difficult to understand. You could add an example of what it's supposed to do, preferably with table DDLs and insert clauses. Then it would be a lot easier for people to give suggestions how to do that.

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL Server? You're using NVL in there.

Comment: I see no `FROM` in the statement. It's incomplete.

Comment: This is a typo "Table 4. COLUMN1" and you actually haev "Table.COLUMN1" there too?

Comment: Not doing something like that in SQL would be loads more effective.

Comment: I have the FROM and WHERE portions of the statement, I also changed the table.column names as not to give out the actual table and column names.

Comment: I basically just put a snip-it of the actual statement, changed the table.column names to generic names to try and get some different ideas as to how this could be written more efficiently.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a "please fix this for me" request.  I am sure people out there are willing to stop what they are doing and fix the query, but this really seems lazy on the poster's part.

Comment: Surely you could use a CTE/`with` clause or subquery to avoid repeating the same fragments many times?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to rewrite the query that should give the same results without nested CASE statements. I'm checking for NULLs first, to potentially short-circuit additional testing. I considered using a single WHEN, with an OR between each expression, but OR isn't deterministic so this may perform better. If those columns are mostly null (vs mostly filled), you could try rewriting it to test for IS NOT NULL instead of IS NULL, and see if there is a performance difference:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 
        Table.Column1 IS NULL
        OR Table.Column2 IS NULL
        OR Table1.Full IS NULL
    THEN 0
    WHEN
        Table.Column1 - Table.Column2 >= 180
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END,
CASE 
    WHEN 
        Table.Column1 IS NULL
        OR Table.Column2 IS NULL
    THEN 0
    WHEN
        Table.Column1 - Table.Column2 >= 180
        AND Table3.DO = 'Z'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END,
CASE 
    WHEN 
        Table4.Column1 IS NULL
        OR Table.Column2 IS NULL
        OR Table2.COLUMN3 IS NULL
    THEN 0
    WHEN
        Table.Column1 - Table.Column2 >= 180
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END,
CASE 
    WHEN 
        Table.Column1 IS NULL
        OR Table.Column2 IS NULL
        OR Table3.Full IS NULL
    THEN 0
    WHEN
        Table.Column1 - Table.Column2 >= 180
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can see here is that you're constantly checking if Table.COLUMN1 is not null and Table.COLUMN2 is not null, and then calculating the difference between them, and if it's greater or equal to 180, then you return 'Y' and you compare this whole thing to 'Y' every time. This same pattern repeats 9 times.

1) Can you have that as a computed column in the table? That would probably simplify things a lot, assuming you need this same formula in other queries too.

2) If that doesn't help, you could make a derived table or CTE, that has the columns you need from your table + this as a extra column:

```
CASE WHEN (Table.COLUMN1) IS NOT NULL AND (Table.COLUMN2) IS NOT NULL 
  THEN CASE WHEN (Table.COLUMN1) - (Table.COLUMN2) >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
ELSE 'N' END
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right. A computed column would work alot better.

Comment: It can be simplified even more, to: `CASE WHEN Table.COLUMN1 - Table.COLUMN2 >= 180 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END`

Answer (score -1):

There is a isnull function in TSQL, writing it something like this might shorten up your query since you are basically checking to see if the column is not null so you can subtract the two columns and see if it is greater than or equal to 180

```
case when isnull(table.column1,0) - isnull(table.column2,0) >= 180 then 'Y' else 'N' end
```